# Apache Cordova: issue updating index.html at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

We'd like to report some issues we are facing developing a Cordova app with Visual Studio Community 2013 adding new code lines in index.html file at runtime in Windows Phone 8.1. It seems that only HTML tags are correctly read and executed, instead JS (included in a  tag or directly in the element tag e.g. using onclick event) is not executed. We ran the same project on both the Android emulator and  physical device and it worked perfectly. Does anybody know wether it's a compatibility issue or something else? Thank you for your attention and help.

The code is:

INDEX.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tester</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="Prova x Emulatore wp" />
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script id="last_script" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

INDEX.JS:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";


    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );
    var logOb;
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.alert('ciao');
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
        document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var el1 = '<input type="button" id="Prova" value="Ciao"/>',
                el2 = '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById(\'Prova\').addEventListener(\'click\', function(){navigator.notification.alert(\'Ciao sono il bottone\')}, false);</script>';
            $('#test').after(el1);
            $('#last_script').after(el2);
        }, false);
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    };

    function onResume() { };

    function onPause() { };
} )();
```

The TrialCode Team.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a JQuery issue where it's not fully loaded before it get used.

I always check that the DOM is ready for using

```
$( document ).ready(......
```

and then check if the device is ready like you have done.